# Errors attempting to use Assimp in DirectX 12

Tags: directx, assimp

I am trying to load a 3D model within a DirectX 12 project by means of Assimp, but even when I write only the importer function, I get errors I can not fix. How do I fix this?

---

Here is my code:

```
void Model::LoadModel(const std::string& FileName)
{
    Assimp::Importer importer;

    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile("coso.fbx",
        aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace |
        aiProcess_Triangulate |
        aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals |
        aiProcess_SplitLargeMeshes |
        aiProcess_ConvertToLeftHanded |
        aiProcess_SortByPType |
        aiProcess_PreTransformVertices);

    if (scene == NULL)
    {

    }
}
```

---

Here are the errors I get:

> Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: struct aiScene const * __cdecl Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const *,unsigned int)" (?ReadFile@Importer@Assimp@@QEAAPEBUaiScene@@PEBDI@Z) Model.obj   1
>
> Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Assimp::Importer::~Importer(void)" (??1Importer@Assimp@@QEAA@XZ) Model.obj  1
>
> Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Assimp::Importer::Importer(void)" (??0Importer@Assimp@@QEAA@XZ) Model.obj   1

Comment: There you go. this came up as "unanswered" on the review queue.

Comment: @Gnemlock Oh, that's odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `assimp.lib` into the list of linked libraries. In Visual Studio's project properties it's in **Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies**. Also add its directory to `Additional Library Directories` in `General`.

Comment: Oh you saved me! I forgot to add the .lib file and now it works fine!